# How to resolve Clan++ error when trying to run IOS simulator in VS2022

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, telerik, maui

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       clang++ exited with code 1:
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lSystem.IO.Compression.Native', '-lSystem.Native', '-lSystem.Net.Security.Native', '-lSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple', '-lcompression', '-lmono-component-debugger', '-lmono-component-diagnostics_tracing', '-lmono-component-hot_reload', '-lmonosgen-2.0', '-lxamarin-dotnet-debug'
ld: building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file (/Users/jaajitech/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/inSisMobileApp/a3a8ad44c41ca6a9c305417349b408b3294f1a61364d707faf7d6c17f11ad8b5/obj/Debug/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/linker-cache/TelerikUI.a[arm64]2) built for 'iOS'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) inSisMobileApp  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.4.7107\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets    1272

getting this error how to resolve this when i trying to run simulator from my windows machine